# Why does .b:not(#a>.b) not work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working with some CSS and wondering why the following piece doesn't work:

```
.container:not(#topic-title>.container)
```

Is there anyway else I can achieve the same thing? I'm open to JavaScript solutions.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RahulDesai I'm trying to style an element that is not a child of another.

Comment: CSS selectors can never go "up" (i.e. back to parent once you descend into children). Your selector asks "A container which does not contain the topic title with another container among its children", presumably not what you wanted. Can you post the full CSS rule you want? Even better, make a fiddle or similar?

Comment: In CSS you can work with children and siblings only, not with parents.

Comment: @Amadan I only have one rule in the statement, `margin: 0 20%`. I've also edited the question, I'm now open to a JavaScript solution.

Comment: @Amadan: I read the selector a little differently: "A container which is not a child of topic-title." Based on the accepted answer I believe that is what the asker intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this selector :

```
:not(#topic-title) > .container
```

```css
.container {
    height:20px;
}
:not(#topic-title) > .container {
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="topic-title">
    <div class="container">parent #topic-title</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="container"> parent not #topic-title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `div` isn't needed here as no element was specified and id could be on a section, main, div, span, li, whatever. `:not(#topic-title) > .container` matches any element (as well as with universal selector `*:not(#topic-title) > .container`)

Comment: @FelipeAls you are right, it's better for further readers. Updated answer

Comment: @FelipeAls `div` was right in my case but you share a good point.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) for the `:not` pseudo class: (bold is mine)

> The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking **a
>   simple selector** (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
>   argument.

where

```
A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, 
attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.
```

Hence `#a>.b` is not a simple selector and that's why the selector `.b:not(#a>.b)` doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example with `background-color`, a `margin` example would be analogous. The idea: set a default page-wide, then cancel for instances where you don't want it.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
}
#topic-title > .container {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="topic-title">
    <div class="container">A</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="container">B</div>
</div>
<div class="container">C</div>
```